# How does a transparent proxy request route back to the client?

Tags: linux, proxy, cdn, bandwidth

I'm looking for a way to obfuscate a request to a web server and instead pull data from a CDN

I believe I need to create a transparent proxy on the web server and pass the request off to the CDN, like so:

client ===>  webserver:80 ====> proxy:someport ===>  cdn.example.com

What I don't know is if the response is routed back through the proxy, effectively charging me for bandwidth twice, like this:

cdn.example.com ====>  proxy:someport ====>  webserver:80  ====> client

Or if the request essentially bypasses the proxy and responds to the client:

cdn.example.com ===> client

I'm also *pretty* sure that the endpoint of the proxy request is not sniffable, but if someone knows otherwise I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm entirely proficient in this, but can't you just return `302 found` and let the client contact the cdn in the first place (maybe even change the url of the files in question, so the client never contacts webserver:80)? Replying like this:

cdn.example.com ===> client

would only be possible by forging the source addresses of the IP packets to the cdn. I'm not sure the ISP of your webserver would allow that.

Comment: The 302 redirect will unfortunately tell the requester where the file is located (I'm essentially trying to obfuscate the ultimate location of a file).  But I think this answers my question - I'd have to forge the source addy of the IP packet, which isn't tenable.